# Get more than 10 posts in a specific category with the wordpress api

Tags: api, rest-api, wp-api

I'm currently building an Ionic app that uses the Wordpress api. I can retrieve posts in a specific category by using the following:

```
// Retrieve filtered data for the categories to show posts.
    function getCategoryName(categoryName) {
        return ($http.get(svampeURL + 'posts?categories=' + categoryName).then(handleSuccess, handleError));
    }
```

The problem is that it only returns 10 as it is some sort of default. I have tried using the per_page=50 argument but it doesn't seem to work. I have also read the documentation of the api and it seems like they don't describe this scenario.

Is there any way to get more than 10 posts in a specific category? How do I change this default return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See if your url is correct. Example: `website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=3&per_page=‌​50`

Comment: It still does not work.. I have tried this call:
http://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=3?posts_per_page=50

It returns an error..

Comment: Sorry, for the WP API the correct is `per_page`  I made a search here and saw that the problem is with your url, the right way of concatenating parameters is with `&` and not `?`. Example: `website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=3&per_page=‌​50`